# Android studio: error: incompatible types: double cannot be converted to String

Tags: java, string, android-studio

I am new to android studio and trying to make a calculator app. Almost all of my buttons are working (0-9), but I only need to program the addition, subtraction, multiply and divide buttons. Now I got a problem:

> error: incompatible types: double cannot be converted to String.

I really don't know how to change this to let it work. Here's a part of my code:

```
//Button A (Addition) Event Handler
    buttonA.setOnClickListener(
            //Button A Interface
            new Button.OnClickListener(){
                //Button A Callback Method
                public void onClick(View v){
                    TextView output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText);
                    tempDouble = Double.parseDouble(output.getText().toString());
                    output.setText("");
                    sign = "+";
                }
            }
    );

    //Button S (Subtract) Event Handler
    buttonS.setOnClickListener(
            //Button S Interface
            new Button.OnClickListener(){
                //Button S Callback Method
                public void onClick(View v){
                    TextView output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText);
                    tempDouble = Double.parseDouble(output.getText().toString());
                    output.setText("");
                    sign = "-";
                }
            }
    );

    //Button D (Divide) Event Handler
    buttonD.setOnClickListener(
            //Button D Interface
            new Button.OnClickListener(){
                //Button D Callback Method
                public void onClick(View v){
                    TextView output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText);
                    tempDouble = Double.parseDouble(output.getText().toString());
                    output.setText("");
                    sign = "/";
                }
            }
    );

    //Button M (Multiply) Event Handler
    buttonM.setOnClickListener(
            //Button M Interface
            new Button.OnClickListener(){
                //Button M Callback Method
                public void onClick(View v){
                    TextView output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText);
                    tempDouble = Double.parseDouble(output.getText().toString());
                    output.setText("");
                    sign = "*";
                }
            }
    );

    //Button Equals
    buttonE.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){
                    TextView output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText);
                    tempDouble2 = Double.parseDouble(output.getText().toString());

                    if (sign .equals("+")){
                        output.setText(Double.toString(tempDouble + tempDouble2));
                    }
                    else if (sign .equals("-")){
                        output.setText(Double.toString(tempDouble - tempDouble2));
                    }
                    else if (sign .equals("X"))){
                        output.setText(Double.toString(tempDouble * tempDouble2));
                    }
                    else if (sign .equals("/")){
                        if (tempDouble2 == 0){
                            //Cannot devide by zero
                            output.setText("X");
                        }
                        else {
                            output.setText(Double.toString(tempDouble / tempDouble2));
                        }
                    }

                    //Reset the Sign variable
                    sign = "";
                }
            }
    );
}
```

Also I get the errors:

> error: bad operand types for binary operator '-'
>
> error: bad operand types for binary operator '*'
>
> error: bad operand types for binary operator '/'

Could someone with some experience help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use '+' operator between two `Double` objects.

If you want to convert a Double to String, you should use

```
String.valueOf(tempDouble);
```

If you want to add two Double objects, you should use

```
tempDouble.doubleValue() + tempDouble2;
```

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible to use 'switch' for the addition, subtraction, multiply and divide buttons? For example write: 4x 'case' and then specify each case with the buttons pressed and what happens next. Is that possible?

Comment: @Mr.Plopkoek `switch` is ok for `String` after jdk 7.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html

Comment: And just one more question: Do I need to know Java and how to work with Eclipse before I can make apps in Android Studio?

Comment: @Mr.Plopkoek  You don't need know how to use Eclipse, but you should know some basic knowledge about Java before making app in Android Studio.