# double cannot be converted to java.lang.String

Tags: java, string

I've tried to work with a bmi calculator but once I've compiled all my code I keep getting the error:

> incompatible types `double` cannot be converted to `java.lang.String`.

```
static String berekenBmi(double gewicht, double lengte) {
    double bmi = gewicht / (lengte * lengte);

    if (bmi < 16) {
        return "Gevaarlijk Ondergewicht";
    } else if (bmi >= 16 && bmi < 18.5) {
        return "Ondergewicht";
    } else if (bmi >= 18.5 && bmi < 25) {
        return "Ideaal gewicht";
    } else if (bmi >= 25 && bmi < 30) {
        return "Overgewicht";
    } else if (bmi >= 30 && bmi < 35) {
        return "Obesitas";
    } else if (bmi > 35) {
        return "Morbide obesitas";
    }
    return bmi;
}
```

I've tried changing my `double` to `String` at the opening statement but that makes things worse.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android studio: error: incompatible types: double cannot be converted to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48731777/android-studio-error-incompatible-types-double-cannot-be-converted-to-string)

Comment: Look at `return bmi;` - what type is `bmi` in this statement? What type does `berekenBmi` return? Nothing in the method needs to change except this statement.

Comment: You can remove the last `return` statement and replace the last `else if()` with a simple `else`, since the case `bmi > 35` is the only one left and doesn't need to be checked. (And you would handle the case where `bmi == 35`).

Comment: @Progman he/she is right. You don't actually need that "else if"

Comment: @Progman actually the behaviour of the code changes, when you remove that last return, as `bmi==35.0` is the only case that is handled by this last `return` - but I have to admit that it probably wasn't intended ... also if it was intended you could replace it with `return "35";` and the problem of conversion from `double` to `String` also would be solved. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `return bmi;` you can try to `return String.valueOf(bmi)`.

This way you don't have control over the form that the double value gets converted to a string (see the JavaDoc of [String.valueOf(double)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(double)).

An alternative would be [String.format(String, Object...)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)), where the first parameter is always the format (e.g. `"%f"`) and the rest are the parameters to format. The format string itself could contain text as well and you can format multiple parameters. It's syntax is documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

With the format string you could e.g. control the number of digits after the decimal point, etc.

UPDATE:
Please note that of your nested ifs one always will return a value, so if you want to combine the BMI value with the text, you could use the string formatter like this:

```java
String berekenBmi(double gewicht, double lengte) {
    double bmi = gewicht / (lengte * lengte);

    String diagnose;

    if (bmi < 16) {
        diagnose = "Gevaarlijk Ondergewicht";
    } else if (bmi >= 16 && bmi < 18.5) {
        diagnose = "Ondergewicht";
    } else if (bmi >= 18.5 && bmi < 25) {
        diagnose = "Ideaal gewicht";
    } else if (bmi >= 25 && bmi < 30) {
        diagnose = "Overgewicht";
    } else if (bmi >= 30 && bmi < 35) {
        diagnose = "Obesitas";
    } else { // bmi >= 35
        diagnose = "Morbide obesitas";
    }
    return String.format("BMI: %.1f (%s)", bmi, diagnose);
}
```

Comment: `return String.format("BMI: %.1f (%s)", bmi, diagnose);` is DEAD CODE.  A better approach would be to simply change the last "else if" to "else".   Read [Anu Martin's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75859564/3135317) response below.

Comment: @FoggyDay you didn't read my code, there is a reason why I posted the full method again. The last `return` is not DEAD CODE, it is the only `return` in the whole method. But you were right about the last if else, so I updated it.

Comment: I'd lose the "diagnose" variable and simply "return" the text strings.  You're [Gold Plating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_plating_(project_management)) (over-complicating) the solution.

Answer (score 0):

**FOR YOUR QUESTION THIS ANSWER IS WRONG, BEST AND EASIEST WAY IS JUST TO DELETE THE LAST RETURN STATEMENT AND UPDATE LAST else if TO JUST ELSE.**

because the last `else if` condition not going to be executed.

Old answer(Not that old)

instead of returning bmi(double variable), just replace it with

```
return String.valueOf(bmi);
```

It will convert double to String.

You have specifically told the compiler, The function will return a String value, but when none of the conditions work on the berekenBmi() function will return a double.

Comment: While true it may be worth mentioning that this line is still dead code sine one of `if`s must be true, meaning that some of previous `return "info";` will be executed and move flow of control out of this method. Proper solution would be removing this line entirely along with last `if(..)` and leaving only `else {..}` so compiler will know that one of `if/else if/else` brunches will be executed.

Comment: Yep, I didn't check it...

Comment: Nope, it's not dead code, for `bmi==35.0` the last return is used (and needed). (Although probably not intentional...;-)

Answer (score 0):

You should return `String` from the method declared to return `String`, but you returned `double`. Change your code with the following

```
return Double.valueOf(bmi).toString();
```

The variable is primitive type, and you cannot use typical `toString()` type conversion. But if you box a value to `Double` then can use it's method to convert the value to `String`.

Also note, that `Double` has different conversions that depends on the current locale. If you need your code to be localized then you have to return different representation of `Double`. It is only the reason to return it as `String`.
Otherwise to convert it to string you should use a `NumberFormatter`.

Comment: We can directly use String.valueOf() method, instead of converting double into Double and then converting it into String, right?

Comment: @AnuMartin You can use this method, but it depends on the String implementation and lacks a localization issue.

Comment: The final return statement is never going to be executed. If he/she just updates accordingly It will fix the issue. The question is not about dt conversion.

Comment: I think it is a good way to show the various ways of reaching the goal, but for that simple example I doubt that localization is an issue.

Comment: @AnuMartin The compiler cannot check all if-else conditions, but a method should have `return` statement according to it's declaration. The error says that it cannot be converted during compilation and should be converted manually. Therefore it *is* about a conversion.

Comment: @cyberbrain In the code there's non-English messages, that should be read in spicific localized app. `Double` representation to `String` must be localized.